# Passing Reference to Pointers

Tags: c++, reference

I'm passing references to pointers in order to use virtual functions.

Option 1 does what I intended and calls the appropriate derived class virtual function. Option 2 does not, suggesting no reference was passed. Since this does compile, then what does `&` mean in this context if not pass by reference?

```
1.
Derived aDerived;
Derived *pDerived = &aDerived;

2.
Derived *pDerived = &Derived();
```

Comment: Option 2 shouldn't compile in standard C++. Also, nowhere are you passing references to pointers here.

Comment: Why do you need to "pass references to pointers in order to use virtual functions"?

Comment: In your first example, `&` is the `address-of` operator, it has nothing to do with references.

Comment: `&` means pass by reference when it's in a function parameter.

Comment: @juanchopanza It's compiling with VS 2015. I'm not sure I understand what you mean - I'm passing references to objects initialized by constructors, or trying to rather in the second case.

Comment: @WhiZTiM Are constructors rvalues?

Comment: @tadman AFAIK polymorphism only works on references so it's either by dynamic allocation or reference - is there a reason not use references?

Comment: @cafekaze That compiler has some a non-standard "extension" that allows you to write this. I'm pretty sure it can be switched off with some flag.

Comment: @cafekaze You. Are. Not. Using. References.

Comment: @cafekaze There's nothing wrong with using references **if you actually use references**. C++ virtual functions work on pointers, there's no need to use references at all if you don't want to. In many cases references help with readability and encourage the compiler to make more optimizations, so they're a good idea, but there's no rule like you're describing. I think you're coming at this with a whole lot of mistaken assumptions that are a symptom of having insufficiently robust reference material. Get [the Bjarne book](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) as a start.

Comment: @juanchopanza Pardon, I meant assigning the address.

Comment: The "trick" is to increase the warning level from default level 3 to level 4. Then you will get a `warning C4238: nonstandard extension used: class rvalue used as lvalue` from VS 2015.

Comment: @tadman I think I just got the terminology mixed up - I'm referring to passing the address to the pointer. I have another function that I want to pass to the pointer either a reference or a pointer. I'm leaning towards pointer as I believe it means I don't have to set the original pointer to NULL. At least, in terms of best practices.

Comment: You really are messing up the terminology. "The address to the pointer" is a pointer to a pointer, which is a whole other thing entirely. I don't know what you're leaning towards here but complete and utter confusion. Please, for your own sanity, get a good reference and start at the beginning. C++ is not something you can just have at and figure out on your own, it's wickedly nuanced.

Comment: @tadman the function returns the address of an object to a pointer... sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @cafekaze What function? There's literally no functions in your code here. Everything is not clear. Please, I know you're trying to learn here, which is fine, but you can't wade into C++ this confused about basic, fundamental terminology and expect to get anywhere. Once you get a grip on the differences between pointers, references, and constructors you'll be much better equipped to understand how to use them.

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks - I see it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In option 2 you are attempting to take the address of an `rvalue`. This should fail to compile with:

> error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand

[Check this live example.](http://ideone.com/3nxA2J)

Comment: Thanks - revised VS warning level to 4 and it showed basically what you mentioned.